# If I'm adding typings to an npm module, how can I depend on global typings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

Say I write a node module, `m`. Later, I decide to add Typescript typings to it. Luckily, the module only exports a single function, so the m.d.ts file is as follows:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />

declare module "m" {
  doThings(b: Buffer): int;

  export = doThings;
}
```

My function uses node's `Buffer`, so I included a valid reference to the node typings in the installed `typings` folder (without it, Sublime gives me the "Cannot find name 'Buffer' message, which seems like a bad thing). Everything looks good, so I update the `typings` key in my `package.json` and deploy.

Separately, I'm using module `m` in a separate typescript project, `p`. I don't have to worry about using `typings`, since my module has types included. When I run `tsc`, I get the following error: `node_modules/m/m.d.ts(6,1): error TS6053: File '/Users/$USER/projects/p/node_modules/m/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts' not found.` That makes a lot of sense, since there isn't a `typings` folder in `node_modules` (I was under the impression checking generated folders like that was discouraged). When a typings file is loaded into DefinitelyTyped, it strips out all of the triple slash references (and the [best practices](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typings-for-npm-packages.html) say that you shouldn't include them in d.ts files). When there's a typings file loaded into an npm module, nothing is stripped out.

So, my question is this: can I have my cake and eat it too? Is it possible to have valid typings in my module (`m`) while not including broken references in external projects (`p`)?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I have my cake and eat it too? Is it possible to have valid typings in my module (m) while not including broken references in external projects (p)?

You don't include `node.d.ts` as a reference tag. Instead you specify that people need to include `node.d.ts` in *their* compilation context e.g. using tsconfig.json.

Comment: Fair enough. Does that mean I live with errors in my module (it'll complain about not knowing buffer) and that's fine?

Comment: `Does that mean I live with errors in my module (it'll complain about not knowing buffer) and that's fine` no. You should have `node.d.ts` in your project as well and included via tsconfig.json.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to include a `tsconfig` because it wasn't a typescript project, just a js project with type definition. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, one more thing, @basarat. I'm working on a ts module (https://github.com/xavdid/word_count) that I then want to use for other things. There doesn't seem to be a good guide for how to write a module that will be consumed by other typescript code, or what the best practices are when it comes to including or ignoring various files. As it stands, when I push that code to npm and require by a fresh module, I'm getting an error that says `Default export of the module has or is using private name 'Options'`. `Options` isn't included in my `index.d.ts`, but seems to be needed?